# Get the first and last row of a group in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
Date       | Value
--------------------
2017-01-02 | 15.6325
2017-01-05 | 15.3285
2017-01-11 | 15.5271
2017-01-29 | 15.9645
2017-02-01 | 15.3595
2017-02-15 | 15.5214
2017-02-20 | 15.8532
2017-03-01 | 15.9638
2017-03-04 | 15.8874
```

With a single sqlite query I need to get the first and the last value of the data grouped by months. Based on this example the result should look something like this:

```
Month   | First value | Last value
----------------------------------------
2017-01 | 15.6325     | 15.9645
2017-02 | 15.3595     | 15.8532
2017-03 | 15.9638     | 15.8874
```

I know how to get this result with two queries, but I would like to know how it is possible to have it with a single query in sqlite.

Comment: Thanks! Edited the date formating

Answer (score 0):

You can look up values with [correlated subqueries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```sql
SELECT Month,
       (SELECT Value
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = Month
        ORDER BY Date ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS FirstValue,
       (SELECT Value
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = Month
        ORDER BY Date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS LastValue
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y-%m', Date) AS Month
      FROM MyTable);
```